# copy value to certain column in different sheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to get the column value from worksheet1 to worksheets2(in specific column), while skipping all the nul/None value in between. My code worked when I printed out all the values in worksheet1 column, exluding all the nul values. However when I saved it to worksheet2, it only showed the last value and duplicate that to the whole column(from row 2 to 20).
Don't know why only last value was written in the new column

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
source_file = (r'XXX(Source file).xlsx')
dest_file = (r'XXX(dest file).xlsx')

wb1=load_workbook(source_file, data_only=True)
wb1.active=0
ws1=wb1.active

wb2=load_workbook(dest_file)
wb2.active=0
ws2=wb2.active

for a in range(9,43):
  cell2 = ws1.cell(row = a, column = 10)
  if cell2.value is None or cell2.value == 0:
     continue
  else:
     print(cell2.value)
     for b in range(2,20):
        ws2.cell(row = b, column=4).value = cell2.value
wb2.save(dest_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is nested so that it will always overwrite all values in the column of the second sheet with the same value from the first.

I'd do something like this:

```
idx = 2
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=9, max_row=43, min_col=10, max_col=10):
    cell = row[0]
    if not cell.value:
        ws2.cell(row=idx, column=4, value=cell.value)
        idx += 1
```

Comment: I have run the code and it seems that it will pick up the "None" or "Nul" value

Comment: Test individual cells and adjust as necessary. The above code will work for `None, 0, ''` but not any strings such as `"None"`